# Drupal 7 - Add Custom entity to a field collection

Tags: entities

I have a custom built using [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) which is fieldable which is working fine till now.

Now I have added a [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) using field UI, but as per project requirement we need the fields inside the field collection to come from a custom entity.

Is there any way of doing this?

Currently in the `entity_info` I have declared the entity as

```
$info['en_projects_details'] = array(
'label' => t('Project Details'),
'base table' => 'en_projects_details',
'entity keys' => array(
  'id' => 'id',
  'label' => 'name',
),
'module' => 'entity_test',
'entity class' => 'ProjectDetailsEntity',
'controller class' => 'ProjectEntityController',
'access callback' => 'entity_test_access_callback',
'uri callback' => 'entity_class_uri',
'fieldable' => FALSE,
'bundles' => array(
  'field_projects_details' => array( //field collection machine name.
    'label' => t('Projects Details  '),
  ),
),
```

I have also created a basic form to be shown as fields in the field collection. But nothing shows up.

Comment: Update: If I add an UI for the entity form the form appears on the page. But not on the field collection.

Comment: If I understand you right, it sounds like you may be a little confused about what a field collection is. It's a fieldable entity in itself. You can't use it to assemble fields from other entities.